# Create custom function in prototype of Boolean that return self value in Integer

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I want to create a custom prototype that convert the self boolean to integer

example

```
let x = true;
x.toInt() // 1
```

I tried to create a custom prototype but I can't find the value

```
Boolean.prototype.testf=() => {console.log(this)}; // don't found value of true
```

Comment: You can just use `+x`...

Comment: Use function, instead. () looses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use arrow functions as they determine their `this` lexically, go with a regular function:

```
 Boolean.prototype.toInt = function() {
   return +this;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`arrow-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) actually uses the current enclosing context, in your code is using the object `window` as context.

> An ***arrow function expression*** has a shorter syntax than a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and does not have its own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target).

*Use either a [`function declaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or [`function expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) instead.*

```js
Boolean.prototype.toInt = function() {
  console.log('' + this);
};

let x = true;
x.toInt();

let y = false;
y.toInt();
```